# HTTP Requests not reaching to tomcat using jersey client

Tags: java, rest, jersey, tomcat7, jersey-client

I am testing REST Apis using jersey client. They are hosted on tomcat7. For some requests, I am not getting any response from the server. When I checked in the logs, then I didn't find any log created by that particular API in catalina.out

I am totally confused what can be the issue. Is it a kind of bug in REST Apis which I am testing or it is some sort of bug in Jersey Client API???

Comment: Please provide your code or what you're trying to do.

Comment: indeed more details would help... if you are not getting anything on "server-side" try to test it with a `curl -v ...` client call and see what it tells you.